# JSON Empty Object being sent as Empty Array (using Angular's $http service)

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs

I'm noticing a strange discrepancy when using `JSON.stringify` to send data via AJAX. I have some values that natively are empty objects, and can be seen as such if I `console.log()` the data being sent through Angular's `$http` service:

[image: Output from console.log()]

Notice that the `columns` variable is an empty object. But when I inspect what's actually being sent via the Network panel, I see:

[image: Output from Chrome's Network panel]

For whatever reason, `columns` has been converted to an empty array. When my app reads this back in from the server, it isn't expecting an empty array, so it errors out. On the one hand, it's an easy fix (just compare and re-assign on load). But does anyone know why this is happening?

I get these results on both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Where are you sending this JSON?  What language is on the backend?  What is it doing with the JSON?

Comment: You are showing the response, not what "is being sent."